# Excel SQL data import parameter issue

Tags: sql, excel, export-to-excel, data-import

I tried to find the answer myself but not knowing how to word the question caused problems :).

I have an excel workbook that I use to pull data from SQL Server 2005 using a stored procedure that accepts a parameter. I am using Microsoft Query in Excel. I am trying to get Excel to grab the parameter from a cell so that the users will not have to edit the connection. If I were to do this as SQL, I would replace the value with a ? and point it to a cell without issue. Since this is a SP, I get a strange response.

**This works**:

```
exec [GTI_mainframe].[proc_mf_forecast_authorizations] .07
```

**This**:

```
exec [GTI_mainframe].[proc_mf_forecast_authorizations] ?
```

**Gives me the following message box**:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid parameter number
```

I control the SP and the excel workbook so can impliment what I need to. I had one person suggest a vba approach to reference the cell value directly. I could do that but my choice would be to not have to do it in macros. I would love to just be able to use the "refresh all" from the data tab in the ribbon bar. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've done this with Views, but not Stored Procedures. What does the SP return? (I thought they just performed actions.)

Comment: They can return lots of different datatypes. In my case, I do a bunch of work with loops and programming calculation stuff for a forecast and I return a table. Both SP and func can take parameters to be used within the code. The returned table becomes a table in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you XLReport; it allows you to connect to almost any database, create queries with parameters.
You can download the trial [here](http://www.xlreport.com/download.htm).

Comment: Using new software is not a option